# Android: Can a static horizontal progress bar be embedded in a Textview?

Tags: android, progress-bar, textview

I don't think this is possible, but can a static (determinate) horizontal progress bar be embedded in a Textview?

Update1: I am trying to create a progress bar similar to that of the iPhone, but I also need text above it.
Here is a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDFU9.png

Update2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<ProgressBar
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/pbar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="45"
    android:maxHeight="5sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypimG.png

Now my goal is to make this look like the previous picture.

Comment: Like @WarrenFaith says, the answers is basically no, but if you explain what you are trying to accomplish, I'm sure we can come up with a bunch of ways to do it.

Comment: @slund: Picture posted of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should look at the gravity attribute for your LinearLayout. Also check margins, paddings, textsize and background. With that you should be able to do nearly the same layout as the on the picture. But don't forget: its not iphone! So you should get the android look and feel. Personally I hate apps that look like an iphone app on my android...

Answer (score 2):

As [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) can't contain another view (there is no addChild() method) the answer is no.

Update: After looking at the picture, you should use a LinearLayout which contains a TextView and a ProgressBar.

Comment: In what type of View should a ProgressBar be placed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```java
Prog = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbar1);
Prog.setProgress((int) rounded);
```