# android - static progress bar in a list

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

I want to implement a static progress bar which displays the data I want. The code in this question looks fine - [Android: Can a static horizontal progress bar be embedded in a Textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117703/android-can-a-static-horizontal-progress-bar-be-embedded-in-a-textview)

Instead of setting android:progress in the xml file, I'll use bar.setProgress() in the code.

I want to display this horizontal bar in a list as a part of the listentry.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CustomListAdapter, see an example below

http://united-coders.com/phillip-steffensen/android-dealing-with-listactivities-customized-listadapters-and-custom-designed-0

Inside the getView() function return the view generated from an xml which contains progress bar and you are done.

Comment: I am able to display the list with progress bar, but I cant set the value of progress bar in the code. android:progress="10" in the xml file works, but if i try doing the same in the code by ProgressBar bar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(android.R.id.progress);    bar.setProgress(30); , it gives a null pointer exception

Comment: The answer for that would depend upon 1) How many such progress bar do you have in the list? 2) Where are you accessing them to set their values?